# How do I read a text file into a 2D list of strings in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a text file that has ASCII symbols as:

```
###@@###%
##@@&&&#%
#@%%%%%%%
```

I need to read this text file to return a 2D list in the form:

```py
[['#','#','#','@','@','#','#','#','%'], 
 ['#','#','@','@','&','&','&','#','%'], 
 ['#','@','%','%','%','%','%','%','%']]
```

However, I am getting my output as:

```py
[['###@@###%'], ['##@@&&&#%'], ['#@%%%%%%%']]
```

This is my code so far:

```py
def readLevel(n):
    '''takes an integer as argument representing the level number
    and reads the appropriate game board file. Returns it as a 
    2D list of strings.'''

    file = open('./levels/ascii_level1.txt','r')

    level = []

    for line in file:
        numString = line.split()
        level.append(numString)

    file.close()

    return level
```

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Use a context manager to handle the file. Why do you need the characters in a list in the first place? Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: *"Why do you need the characters in a list in the first place?"* Possibly because lists are mutable, whereas strings are not.

Comment: It's part of the assignment requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a string to a list of characters using `list`:

```py
    for line in file:
        numString = list(line)
        level.append(numString)
```

This works because `list` converts any type of sequence to a list, and a string is a sequence of characters.

The `line.split()` method doesn't work for this, since it splits on whitespace, but the string doesn't contain any whitespace. In some languages, you can call the equivalent method like `.split('')` with an empty separator to split a string into individual characters, but this is an error in Python.